# Some Chinese font can't be displayed using iTextpdf

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, cjk, itextpdf

In the following code:

```
static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document document = new Document();
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("PDF_FILE"));
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
    document.open();
    BaseFont STXiHei = BaseFont.createFont("STXiHei.ttf",  BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    BaseFont SongTi = BaseFont.createFont("SongTi.ttc,6", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    document.add(new Paragraph("华文细黑", new Font(STXiHei)));
    document.add(new Paragraph("宋体", new Font(SongTi)));
    document.close();
}
```

Only the 2nd font `宋体` will display, so what if I want to use the 1st font `华文细黑`? Is this caused by the encoding wrong?

Comment: Maybe `STXiHei.ttf` doesn't support UNICODE. [Have you checked the encodings that are supported?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11#435-encodingnames.java)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, using the example, I can see that STXiHei supports CP1252 and CP936 Chinese, while SongTi supports a lot other encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I still do not completely understand the reason, my problem is solved by using `STXihei.ttf` from Windows instead of the one from Mac. Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I couldn't reproduce the problem, hence I didn't know what to answer...